# foreach() with Laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I have one question, maybe it's really stupid, sorry. For example, I have "Users" table and I need to perform some action with each user (not with all users so I can't use bulk update. Just imagine this situation).

Is there any difference between:

```
$users = Users::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    //some action
}
```

and

```
foreach (Users::all() as $user) {
        //some action
}
```

Appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Nothing different but it's better to use first method in above code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: @SagarGautam why is that?

Comment: @Scuzzy It depends on the context. If you might need again Users::all() then you better off assign it to a variable instead of making another query to the database.

Comment: But in this explicit example?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do in the loop?

Comment: @Ross Wilson I need to check Stripe subscription status of each user and send the order if I have new success payment. So I really need to loop all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your situation. Personally I find readability the key. Using 'one use' variables is mostly more readable.